# OLS model specification that includes all dummy variables with a predetermined coefficient

Tags: r, regression, python, least-squares, categorical-encoding

I'm working with a OLS model that includes dummy variables (quarters of year). Here's what I would specify it:

$$y = \beta X + \gamma_1Q_1 + \gamma_2Q_2 + \gamma_3Q_3 + \epsilon$$

However, in the material I'm reading, the model specification is instead like this:

$$y = \beta X + \gamma_1Q_1 + \gamma_2Q_2 + \gamma_3Q_3 + (0-\gamma_1-\gamma_2-\gamma_3)Q_4 + \epsilon$$

So in essence the model include all dummy quarters but with the coefficient for `Q4` is pre-determined by the other three.

My questions are:

1/ How does that specification avoid the dummy trap?
2/ I see this difference result in different estimates of coefficients $\beta$ and $\gamma$'s. Why is that?
3/ Given such a difference, what specification is better?
4/ Finally, I'm working with EViews if you know what it is. But it would be great if you can give a hint on how to put it in R or, more preferably, Python. I can do without $Q_4$ like this (assuming dataframe is prepared):

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = df[['x', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']]
y = df['y']
ols_model = sm.OLS(y, X, missing = 'drop')
ols_fit = ols_model.fit()
```

But I don't know how to add $Q_4$ to the model as in the other specification.

Comment: Do you know if either model is fit with an intercept?

Comment: @Noah Neither of these have an intercept. Would it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the second model like this: $$y = \tilde \beta X + \tilde \gamma_1 \cdot (Q_1 - Q_4) + \tilde \gamma_2 \cdot (Q_2 - Q_4) + \tilde \gamma_3 \cdot (Q_3 - Q_4) + \varepsilon$$

You can estimate this model by subtracting $Q_4$ from the other three before you fit the model. This still avoids the dummy variables trap, even if you have an intercept in X.

The coefficients will be different since the quarter variables on the RHS are transformed by subtracting $Q_4$. You have imposed a constraint on the $\tilde \gamma$ coefficients that they add up to zero. This is why I added tildes and changed the error in the equation above. These coefficients represent the difference in the predicted value of the dependent variable when comparing one quarter to the average of all the other quarters instead of relative to $Q_4$ (if that is the omitted quarter).

You can do a likelihood ratio test with the two models to decide which is better.